# Proper way to handle errors in redux using redux-promise

Tags: redux, redux-promise

I'm trying "redux-promise".
When there's no error in the flow, my code works properly. But, let's say that the API is down or I have a typo in the URL. In those cases, I expect to handle the error in the proper way.

This is the `API`: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
(in the snippet I'm adding random text at the end to produce the 404)

**Action creator**

```
export async function fetchUsers() {

  const request = await axios
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userssdfdsfdsf')
    .catch(error => console.log('ERROR', error))

  return {
    type: FETCHING_USERS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHING_USERS:
      return [...state, ...action.payload.data]

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I can see the error logged in the console

```
ERROR Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

But, once the action is dispatched its payload is `undefined`

`action {type: "FETCHING_USERS", payload: undefined}`

I don't know where is the best place to handle this: action creator, reducer, etc. I shouldn't check if payload is something in the reducer and, if not, return state or do nothing. I want to understand which would be the best approach to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [source](https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise/blob/master/src/index.js) of redux-promise, as it very simple.

Redux-promise expects either `promise` or action with payload set to some `promise`. I think you're going to use leter case.

Code may look like (just example, not tested):

```
export function fetchUsers() {

    const request = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userssdfdsfdsf');

    return {
        type: FETCHING_USERS,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

In  this case redux-promise will await for resolution of promise returned by `axios.get` and dispatch your action but `payload` replaced with promise result. In case of error, redux-promise will catch it and dispatch action with `error = true` (you may want to handle `action.error === true` case in reducer)

Answer (score 0):

In the reducer you should check for the existence of the error field in action:

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
  if (action.error) {
    //handle
  }  
  switch(action.type) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for the action.

`export const fetchUsers = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userssdfdsfdsf');
    dispatch({
      type: FETCHING_USERS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCHING_ERROR
    });
  }
};`

In reducer do this.
Define the initial state and use this code.

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case FETCHING_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        user: payload,

      };
case FETCH_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        loading: false,
      };
```